# Deeplinking - how to open a deeplink from React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, deep-linking

I would like to open a deep link url from a React app with a schemelike:

```
<DEEP_LINK_SCHEME>://someInfor?param
```

but when I use:

```
history.push(url);
```

The URL I get redirected to contains my app as the base. Is there an alternative for opening link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So to answer my own question this works:

```
window.location.assign(url)
```